# How to handle BAD_ACCESS signal handling in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, exception, signal-handling

I am trying to handle the crashes and when ever a crash occurred I want to store some log into a file.

till now what I tried is

```
void InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler()
{
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleException);
    signal(SIGABRT, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGILL, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGSEGV, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGFPE, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGBUS, SignalHandler);
    signal(SIGPIPE, SignalHandler);
}
static void SignalHandler (int signo) {
    //...
    NSLog(@"\n Inside Signal Handler Method...");
}
void HandleException(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", exception);
    NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
    // Internal error reporting
}
```

So when I get a BAD_ACCESS exception the control is not getting into the signal handler method.

I am calling this InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler() method in applicationDidFinishLaunching method of AppDelegate

Can anyone suggest what wrong I did? or any suggestion to handle both exceptions and signals..

Answer (score 0):

Before starting to handle signals yourself you may want to read up on safe signal handling. `man sigaction` is a first start. See the note "The following functions are [...] async-signal safe".

In a signal handler you can't use Objective-C or NSLog, for example. This could be a reason for your signal handler not working as expected.

As ususal with low level stuff, [Mike Ash has a nice article](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-04-01-signal-handling.html).

Answer (score -1):

Write the below method in your AppDelegate.m

```
//Function to Caught Exceptions
- (void)installUncaughtExceptionHandler
{
    InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler();
}
```

And call the above method this way in **applicationDidFinishLaunching** method of **AppDelegate.m**

```
[self performSelector:@selector(installUncaughtExceptionHandler) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Comment: Please explain what's the sense of installing the exception handler in this delayed fashion.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Please see the code one more time, as it is not installing the exception handler with any delay as I pass 0 to the parameter. It just call the method of installing on the other thread.

Comment: The question is about signal handling which is unaffected by threads.